# finding the longitude and latitude bound box of a country using javascript?

Tags: javascript, twitter, latitude-longitude

I am trying to find the longitude and latitude bound box of a country:

this is for San Francisco:

```
// filter the public stream by the latitude/longitude bounded box of San Francisco

var sanFrancisco = [ '-122.75', '36.8', '-121.75', '37.8' ]
```

how can i find the bound box for Kuwait the country.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the latitude and longitude , you can [calculate the bounding box](http://janmatuschek.de/LatitudeLongitudeBoundingCoordinates).
You can also use [this website](http://boundingbox.klokantech.com/), that would calculate this for you.